# How to break line in jQueryUI tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

The new version of jQueryUI (1.9) comes with the native tooltip widget. After testing with it, it works fine if the content (value of the title attribute) is short. But if the content is long, the tooltip, once displayed, will overlap the input text.

<strike>There is [**a demo**](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) on the official site.</strike>

When you hover the mouse cursor over the **Your age** text `<input>`, the tooltip displayed overlaps the text input. I am not sure if this is the desired behaviour of the widget.
I would like it to stay on the right side of the text input and break lines if necessary.

**Edit:** The demo page no longer shows the original problem since the demo has been updated to use jQueryUI v1.10 in which the *position* code was updated to better place the tooltip - see http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position

I have re-created a [demo of the original problem on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kECuc/).

Comment: Updated with a jsFiddle demo, since the official demo no longer shows the problem with the latest version of jQuery. Also updated my answer on how to add line breaks.

Comment: +1 for including jsFiddle demos

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The [**placement**](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) of the tooltip is controlled by a jQueryUI Position object and the default settings are:

```
{ my: "left+15 center", at: "right center", collision: "flipfit" }
```

The [**Position**](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) Object, in particular the `collision` attribute can be changed to force placement of the control somewhere else. The default for tooltips is *flipfit* which means the if the default (on the right) does not fit it will *flip* to the left and try that position and if that doesn't collide with anything, try to *fit* the control by moving it away from the edge of the window. The result is that it now collides with the `<input>`. There doesn't seem to be an option to force a long tooltip to cleverly wrap.

However there are two ways to wrap the content:

Add a custom CSS class to the configuration with a `max-width` to force wrapping, for example:

JavaScript

```
$('input').tooltip({
    tooltipClass:'tooltip'
});
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    max-width:256px;
}
```

Or insert hard line-breaks `<br/>` in the title attribute, for example

```
title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/>consectetur adipisicing elit"
```

**Edit:** So it looks like jQueryUI changed the tooltip *content* option between v1.9 and v1.10 (according to [the changelog](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0/#tooltip)). For reference here is the difference:

**v1.9.2**

```
content: function() {
    return $( this ).attr( "title" );
}
```

**v1.10**

```
content: function() {
    // support: IE<9, Opera in jQuery <1.7
    // .text() can't accept undefined, so coerce to a string
    var title = $( this ).attr( "title" ) || "";
    // Escape title, since we're going from an attribute to raw HTML
    return $( "<a>" ).text( title ).html();
}
```

So you can put back the older functionality that does not escape `<br/>` tags in the *title* attribute by using the `.tooltip()` like this:

```
$('input').tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }
});
```

Also, see [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/grJxQ/1/).

Comment: Which version of jQueryUI are you using?

Comment: It is working with `<br/>` in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/grJxQ/) with jQuery v1.9.1 and jQueryUI v1.9.2

Comment: That demo does work. I'm using jQuery v1.9.1 and UI v1.10 hosted on jquery.com, and it's not working.

Comment: OK so the question was about v1.9. Maybe it is no longer working in v1.10. I'll have another look with this new version.

Comment: @drolex Updated answer for v1.10

Comment: Note that if your tooltip text includes greater than / less than symbols, e.g. '<file>', plain old &lt; and &gt; won't work.  You'll need to double escape it with '&amp;lt;file&amp;gt;'.

Comment: You are a champ. The following worked for me.
$('input').tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }
});

Answer (score 14):

This is my trick to do it with latest jquery / jqueryui

It's assuming all of the items you want to have tooltips have class 'jqtooltip', they have title tags, and the title has a pipe character for a line separator.

```
$('.jqtooltip').tooltip({ 
  content: function(callback) { 
     callback($(this).prop('title').replace('|', '<br />')); 
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a great idea, I will have to try it to get my images loaded as well.

Comment: To replace more than just the first |, use `replace(/\|/g, '<br />')`

Answer (score 12):

I have a solution for jQuery 2.1.1, similar to @Taru's solution.

Basically, we have to use tooltip's content call to dynamically get the data from the element. The element itself can have any html markup in it. Note that you need to import

So, onload, I do this:

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      content:function(){
        return this.getAttribute("title");
      }
    });
  });
```

And my example element is this:

```
<div title="first<br/>second<br/>">hover me</div>
```

Comment: Works with JQuery UI `v1.11.4` and JQuery `v1.10.2`

Comment: Works with JQuery UI 1.11.3 and JQuery  2.1.3 - Best solution of all!

Answer (score 2):

This works:

**HTML**

```
<div class="produtos">
    <div class="produtos_imagem">
        <img src="imagens/teste/7.jpg" width="200" title="Código: 00122124<br /><br />Descrição: AB PNEU 700 X 23 FOLD CORPRO<br /><br />Unidade: PN<br /><br />Marca : PNEU"/>
    </div>
    <p class="produtos_titulo">AB PNEU 700 X 23 FOLD CORPRO</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
            return element.attr( "title" );
        }
    },
    position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official jQuery UI's documentation https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/ for the tooltip widget (version 1.13), I've used this syntax to set an html content with linebreaks :

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip( "option", "content", "1st line.<br />2nd line.<br />3rd line." );
```

It works fine on my side.
Also works the solution provided by andyb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13068935/11292902) that aims at valuing the content by the title attribute's value :

```
$('input').tooltip({
 content: function() {
    return $(this).attr('title');
 }
});
```