# Allow <BR> or New Line to jquery tooltip

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to know how do I make a new line inside of the tooltip and also make the tooltip more wider

I tried to add a `<br>, <br />, <br/>, \n, /n, &#013;, &#10;` ... NOTHING SEEMS TO BE WORKING :(

I also tried to add the following script but I don't know if I did it correctly or if it's useful

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('.tooltip ').tooltiptext({
          contentAsHTML: true,
    });
});
</script>
```

CODE:

```
<script>
    // On first hover event we will make popover and then AJAX content into it.

    $('[data-poload]').hover(function(event) {
      var el = $(this);
      // Commenting this (For testing purposes)
      $.get(el.data('poload'), function(d) {
        // set new content
        el.find('.tooltiptext').text(d);
      });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: table;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 10px;

        /* Position the tooltip */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        top: -5px;
        left: 105%; 
    }
</style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="tooltip" data-poload="//demo2307137.mockable.io/test">
       <img src="alerts.gif"/>
       <br/><br/><br/>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Loading...</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tooltip" data-poload="testpage.php?id=123">
       <img src="alerts.gif"/>
       <br/><br/><br/>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Loading...</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the content as text... use `html()` instead of `text()`

```
 $.get(el.data('poload'), function(d) {
    // set new content
    el.find('.tooltiptext').html(d);
  });
```

Comment: Any idea how to make the tooltip width that of the text ? because if the text is too long it the tooltip will end but the text continues and looks really ugly. I know the width is at .tooltip .tooltiptext {width: 120px; but I want it to be sized automatically, I tried to set it to 100% but it doesn't really work.

Comment: depends what plugin you are using and what features it has

Comment: no plugin, what you see in the code is what I have. it's ok I will just size it to 240px and should not need more room than that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

See: [jQuery tooltip add line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599562/jquery-tooltip-add-line-break)

And: [How to break line in jQueryUI tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066909/how-to-break-line-in-jqueryui-tooltip)

Use Tooltip content http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

```
$( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: "img, [data-geo], [title]",
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[data-geo]" ) ) {
          var text = element.text();
          return "<img class='map' alt='" + text +
            "' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
            "zoom=11&size=350x350&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&center=" +
            text + "'>";
        }
        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "title" );
        }
        if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "alt" );
        }
      }
    });
  } );
```